# Do I need to notify cron about changes in /etc/crontab?

Tags: cron

I have edited the system crontab table using `sudo nano /etc/crontab` according to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127734/63587) I found online. Will that be sufficient to run the job or do I need to "notify" or "refresh" `cron` with a command after I edited the file?

Also, [the Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/sysrescron-24589.html) said I should validate the file using `crontab -l`, but that command only lists the crontab for root, not the system crontab. How would I validate the system crontab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to edit the cron directly.  You should use `crontab -e` to edit cron files as per [that answer on a sister site to Ask Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127734/63587)...

That being said according to the cron manual page:

> There are two ways how changes in crontables are checked.  The first
>   method is checking the modtime of a file.  The second method is using
>   the inotify support.  Using of inotify is logged in the /var/log/cron
>   log after the daemon is started.  The inotify support checks for
>   changes in all crontables and accesses the hard disk only when a
>   change is detected.

So you should *very probably* be safe and your cron job will run.

The validation the Oracle site is talking about is a visual validation that you didn't do something stupid like exit your editor without saving your file...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu at least there's no need to power cicle cron to see new additions ( however you can if it worries you via `sudo service crond restart` ). You can `grep cron /var/log/syslog` and see if your command ran.

Comment: Given a long delay for the command to run, I could only check the log in 4 months. And I don't want to run it now